# Loading partial view using ajax the submit button is fired

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-mvc-partialview

When I am loading a partial view with ajax the submit button is fired.
If I remove/delete the submit button the partial view is rendered properly.

This is my javascript code:

```
$(".searchclientssendsms").keypress(function (event) {

    var keycode = (event.keycode ? event.keycode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') { //enter key

             var value = $(this).val();

             $.get("/smstemplate/SearchClients/" + value,

             function (data) {             
                $('#searchClientsResult').html(data);               
             });

    }
});
```

The line from RouteConfig regarding my search :

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "SearchClientsSendSMS", 
                  url: "smstemplate/searchclients/{search}", 
             defaults: new { controller = "smstemplate",
                                 action = "searchclients" });
```

And the functions from controller:

```
    public ActionResult SendSMS()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SendSMS(SMSTemplate sms, string[] clients)
    {

        foreach (string client in clients)
        {
            int idclient = Convert.ToInt32(client);
            Customer customer=db.Customers.Find(idclient);
           // SendSMS(customer.Phone, sms.Text);
        }

        return View();
    }


    public ActionResult SearchClients(string search)
    {
        List<Customer> clients = db.Customers.Where(c => c.Deleted == true && (c.Email.Contains(search) || c.Name.Contains(search) || c.Phone.Contains(search))).ToList();

        return PartialView(clients);
    }
```

If I execute the javascript function from firebug the partial view is rendered corrected. The submit button is not fired any more.

```
 $.get("/smstemplate/SearchClients/poir",

        function (data) {

            $('#searchClientsResult').html(data);

        });
```

I noticed this behaviour only at enter key.

So, what can cause that?

Comment: when form is posting?? at which specific event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that the `Enter` key is also submitting the button, so it is calling the AJAX and pressing button at the same time.

Try this:

```
$(".searchclientssendsms").keypress(function (event) {

var keycode = (event.keycode ? event.keycode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') { //enter key

         var value = $(this).val();

         $.get("/smstemplate/SearchClients/" + value,

         function (data) {             
            $('#searchClientsResult').html(data);               
         });

         event.preventDefault(); //Inside the if so only is prevented for Enter Key.

    }
});
```

And to disable it in all the page you could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).keydown(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
   });
});
```

Comment: Now I can't type into input text. I noticed that if I press enter in any input from this view the submit button is fired.

Comment: @Otix That's the default action for Enter Key, submit the form. Make sure the event.preventDefault() is inside the if block, if not it will prevent any key to be pressed. Take a look to the code I added.

Comment: Your solution works! I placed the event.preventDefault() before the line where I get the input value. But my question now is how can I remove this behaviour(enter key) for entire page.

Comment: @Otix Added to the answer how to remove it for entire page, should work.